# jQuery Validate not working in IE8 and Safari

Tags: jquery, validation, internet-explorer-8, safari

jQuery Validate works great in Firefox and Chrome, validating both client-side and sending the POST to php email function. But in IE8 and Safari it skips directly to server-side validation so that the user has to use the Back button to fill in required fields.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form1").validate( {
        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true
                },
            email: {
                required: true
                }
        }
    )};
});
</script>
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<form class="cmxform" action="" method="post" name="WCForm" id="form1" />
<fieldset>
<input name="name" type="text" required="required" id="name" size="25" />
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happened to the responses? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To start, the selector should have a # for the id:

```
$("#form1")
```

Also, shouldn't the input be inside the form instead of having the form tag self-closed?

```
<form class="cmxform" action="" method="post" name="WCForm" id="form1">
    <input name="name" type="text" required="required" id="name" size="25" />
</form>
```